# Setting a controls height to "match_parent" makes its parent bigger?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am attempting to make a card view with some text and an image inside it.

[image: This is what I want]

I want the card view to be just big enough for the textviews which each can wrap to multiple lines so I want the card to scale based on the text, I also want the image to fill the height of the card whatever it may be.

So I set the card view and the linear layout containing the textviews height to wrap_content, and the image views height to match_parent.

However setting the images to match_parent makes the whole card bigger meaning its much bigger than needed for the text?

Is there any way around this or some alternative method to achieve the same effect?

EXTRA INFORMATION:

I think I know why this is happening, Its because the image views desired size based on the size of the image is bigger than the card so if the cards height is match_parent it will get as big as its parent allows until it reaches the size of the original image. Because the height of its parent is wrap_content it lets the image view get that big. I'm still no wiser on how to stop this happening though other than scaling down the image but this would mean it gets pixelated?

Comment: If your lineairlayout has a vertical orientation and you set the imageView's height to match parent you leave no room for anything else in the layout. This will most likely result in some unexpected behaviour. Actually, i'm not sure what you're trying to do here, some code and / or picture of what you're trying to create might be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what ended up working for this was to have both items in a relative layout and then align the image view to the top and bottom of the linear layout containing the text kinda like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text"/>

        <LinearLayout                
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t fully understand your problem but maybe you can do something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_Parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/layout_ImageView"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/layout_Text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This way the ImageView will only take the space left for it depending of the text.